# What really is `const labels: { [foo: string]: string } =` and can I do better?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I have written a piece of code like the following, and "it works" (I compile my code with TypeScript 3.7):

```js
const something: { [foo: string]: string } =  <...> ;
```

I don't want to focus on the right-hand side of the `=`. `<...>` is a placeholder for actual code.

I would like to precisely understand: **What is the construct on the left-hand side? How do we call that? Which pieces is it comprised of (and how we call those), and** **which guarantees does it actually provide?**

I briefly thought of `{ [foo: string]: string }` as an anonymous interface declaration, but searching the web for this term only confirms that I should better *know* instead of *think* :-). Which brings me here.

I should say what I found. I looked up the TS spec. I found that `{ [foo: string]: string }` probably is an [Object Type Literal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.3) where the inner part (the `TypeBody`) seems to be an [Index Signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#394-index-signatures). An index signature seems to be comprised of `[ BindingIdentifier : string ] TypeAnnotation`. I must say that after reading section `3.9.4 Index Signatures` things are not clear to me yet, at all. In particular: what is the role of `BindingIdentifier`, `foo` in my case? I found that the `foo` in the code shown can be anything really (things compile and run fine with `key`, `x`, `bar` instead of `foo`), and I find that confusing, it's a code smell. Can I get away w/o a `foo`, i.e. without a `BindingIdentifier`? I think this last part relates to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7803 but this discussion was not really concluded and it's been a few years.

Secondly, here is what my intent is: I would like to declare the variable `something` with an inline type expression which is supposed to imply that the value must be an object comprised exclusively of `string` keys and `string` values. Based on the feedback from `tsc` I think my attempt achieves that. But is that really the case, and is there cleaner way to achieve that?

Comment: "*the value must be an object comprised exclusively of `string` keys and `string` values*" any amount of keys/values, correct? And they will not be nullable, I assume.

Comment: `const` means the ref will forever reference the right hand side.

Comment: @VLAZ "any amount of keys/values, correct? And they will not be nullable, I assume": yes, confirmed!

Comment: btw about the state of _documentation_ I naively submitted an issue, just to learn that "Forget about the spec. It's not maintained at all and heavily outdated. The last real update was done in January 2016, almost 3 years ago. So realistically TypeScript has no specification anymore." -- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's guaranteeing that something will be a JavaScript object (and cannot be undefined) with string keys and string values (which again cannot be undefined).

I personally try to keep inline literals quite sparing, so I would more normally export this into a separate type, e.g.

```
interface MySomething {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Additionally, and because this is such a common construct, I've created my one and only global type to be able to use this natively wherever. It's a `Dict` type, and looks like this:

```
// src/global.d.ts
declare interface Dict<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

This means I can, in such situations, simply have ...

```
const something: Dict<string> = <...>;
```

Addressing another of your points, the name of the key is indeed arbitrary, but I have found that it's helpful with such things to give it a sensible name, according to what it's representing, as a form of code-as-documentation for anyone using that type.

Comment: Lovely reply, thank you. About the "the name of the key is indeed arbitrary, but I have found that it's helpful with such things to give it a sensible name, according to what it's representing" -- is that the primary intent of this part of the type annotation, or does the compiler indeed look at the specific choice, and does it evaluate it in some way, maybe depending on usage?

Comment: Also just found https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html which says "TIP: the name of the index signature e.g. index in { [index:string] : {message: string} } has no significance for TypeScript and is only for readability". Still looking for a corresponding statement in the spec.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just for readability, not Typescript, but readability is pretty important! :)